# How to stop dropdown list appearing on top of list item

Tags: html, css, web, styling

So I'm trying to configure a simple dropdown list from a list item but I can't for the life of me figure out why it wont stop covering the list item when I hover over it. Here's the html:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="float:right">
                <li><a class="active dropbtn" href="">Profile</a></li>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="logout.php?logout"><span class="glyphicon   glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp; Logout</a></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the css to style this is:

```
tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
th, td {
padding: 15px;
text-align: left;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
position: relative;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 10;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown     content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #3e8e41;
```

In addition to this, despite changing the z-index of the dropdown elements I can't get the menu to appear outside of the menu where the parent list is located

All help is appreciated

Comment: You have some problems in both the html & css, you should fix it. And I'm not so sure what exactly the problem is. Please try to explain better (what happen that you don't want? What do you expect to see?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code gave me a few errors.... Please look at this JSfiddle and tell me if it's working now? Also please, tell me what you want because I'm a bit confused..

https://jsfiddle.net/xxsycmyj/

```
<div class="dropdown" style="float:left">
            <li><a class="active dropbtn" href="">Profile</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="logout.php?logout"><span class="glyphicon   glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp; Logout</a>
            </div>
```

The CSS looked fine to me.